# CRTP inheriting from its default instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, template-meta-programming, crtp

I need to represent a hierarchy like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct X
{
};

template<typename Derived = void>
struct Y : Y<void>
{
    //Note: not trying to use SFINAE here
    using DerivedType = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Y, Derived>::value, Derived>::type;
};
template<>
struct Y<void> : X<Y<void>>
{
};

struct Z : Y<Z>
{
};
```

Both Z and Y<void> need to be instantiable:

```cpp
W<Y<>> wy;
W<Z> wz;
```

All Y<T> need to be instances of Y<void>, and if possible I would prefer not to have two different names to make it work. (That is my last resort)

The problem is, I don't know how to make this work. The above code obviously doesn't work as intended and doesn't compile. Is there a way I can make it work, or do you have any recommendations for alternatives besides the one I already mentioned?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The `std::enable_if` won't trigger SFINAE, but rather a hard error. Not too different from `static_assert(std::is_base_of<Y,Derived>::value)`

Comment: I'm not trying to use SFINAE here, it's supposed to trigger a hard error.

Comment: Then it would be clearer if it was stated as a `static_assert` :) The effect from the compiler's point of view would be the same, but it is clearer to other maintainers.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'll make sure to use that instead then - it certainly seems better.

Comment: BTW, in the implementation above, the nested type will always be `void`, you forgot to add `Derived` as the second argument of `enable_if` (which is yet another reason to split into a `static_assert` and a simpler `typedef`/`using` declaration both of which are much simpler to write and read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about reordering it:

```
template <typename> struct Y;

template <> struct Y<void> : X<Y<void>> { };

template <typename T = void> struct Y : Y<void> { };
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I made corrections to your answer because you inherited the wrong thing and left off the default value.

Comment: @LB--: Oh OK, I see. I added those changes now.